# how to create dashed line separator using iTextSharp in vb.net

Tags: itext

I have gone through the custom dotted line separator example but unable
    do it in visual basic is there any example in vb

I am getting following errors

1)'Dash' is already declared as 'Protected Friend dash As Single' in this class.

2)'Phase' is already declared as 'Protected Friend phase As Single' in this class.

3)'LineWidth' is not a member of 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte'.

4) Variable 'Dash' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null 
   reference exception could result at runtime.

5) Variable 'Phase' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null
   reference exception could result at runtime.

6) sub 'draw' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'DottedLineSeparator'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'.

```
 Option Strict On
 Option Explicit On

Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     
Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine 
(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Customers.pdf")
    'Dim PageSize As New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle 
(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4)
    Dim Document As Document = New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4,  
50, 10, 10, 10)

    Try
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, New System.IO.FileStream(FileName, 
  System.IO.FileMode.Create))

        Document.Open()

        Dim separator As New CustomDashedLineSeparator()
        separator.dash = 10
        separator.Gap = 7
        separator.LineWidth = 3
        Dim linebreak As New Chunk(separator)
        Document.Add(linebreak)


        Document.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Pdf is Created")
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
Friend Class CustomDashedLineSeparator
Inherits pdf.draw.DottedLineSeparator

Protected Friend dash As Single = 5
Protected Friend phase As Single = 2.5F
Public Overridable Property Dash As Single
    Get
        Return Dash
    End Get
    Set(ByVal dash As Single)
        Me.dash = dash
    End Set
End Property
Public Overridable Property Phase As Single
    Get
        Return Phase
    End Get
    Set(ByVal phase As Single)
        Me.phase = phase
    End Set
End Property

Public Overridable Sub draw(ByVal canvas As PdfContentByte, ByVal llx As  
Single, ByVal lly As Single, ByVal urx As Single, ByVal ury As Single,  
ByVal y As Single)
    canvas.SaveState()
    canvas.LineWidth = LineWidth
    canvas.SetLineDash(dash, Gap, phase)
    DrawLine(canvas, llx, urx, y)
    canvas.RestoreState()
 End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: What example? What problems are you having?

Comment: Dear  Chris Haas  I have given my codes  and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic is generally case-insensitive unlike C# and Java. You have both a property and field named `Dash` and also the same with `Phase`. That's your first two errors as well as your fourth and fifth. You can fix this by renaming your fields. One common way is to just prefix them with underscores.

For the third error, you need to use the `SetLineWidth()` method instead of using the `LineWidth` property.

For your sixth error, you are trying to override a method without explicitly telling VB that you want to. To do that you need to use `Overrides` instead of `Overridable`.

Your cleaned up class should look like this:

```
Friend Class CustomDashedLineSeparator
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.DottedLineSeparator

    Protected Friend _dash As Single = 5
    Protected Friend _phase As Single = 2.5F
    Public Overridable Property Dash As Single
        Get
            Return Dash
        End Get
        Set(ByVal dash As Single)
            Me._dash = dash
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overridable Property Phase As Single
        Get
            Return _Phase
        End Get
        Set(ByVal phase As Single)
            Me._phase = phase
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub Draw(ByVal canvas As PdfContentByte, ByVal llx As Single, ByVal lly As Single, ByVal urx As Single, ByVal ury As Single, ByVal y As Single)
        canvas.SaveState()
        canvas.SetLineWidth(LineWidth)
        canvas.SetLineDash(Dash, Gap, phase)
        DrawLine(canvas, llx, urx, y)
        canvas.RestoreState()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**However**, I'm betting that you don't really need those internal properties in the first place. If not, you can make that class even simpler:

```
Friend Class CustomDashedLineSeparator
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.DottedLineSeparator

    Public Property Dash As Single
    Public Property Phase As Single

    Public Overrides Sub Draw(ByVal canvas As PdfContentByte, ByVal llx As Single, ByVal lly As Single, ByVal urx As Single, ByVal ury As Single, ByVal y As Single)
        canvas.SaveState()
        canvas.SetLineWidth(LineWidth)
        canvas.SetLineDash(Dash, Gap, phase)
        DrawLine(canvas, llx, urx, y)
        canvas.RestoreState()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Lastly, please never `try/catch` giant blocks of code. At best, your app will politely crash however you'll have no idea why and you'll never be able to fix it. Although not as pretty "Unable to open file XYZ.pdf for writing" is way more helpful than "Unable to create PDF".